# Why can't variables local to a method be declared final?

Tags: java, scope, final, local-variables

I like to know why Variables that are local to a method cannot be declared final.
Is there any specific reason?

Does it mean are there no local constants in Java?

Comment: Please either cite a reference or give example code (and compiler, with any compile error).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They can be declared final. Your actual problem lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 5):

From the [Java specification §4.5.4](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/typesValues.doc.html):

> **A variable can be declared final**. A final variable may only be assigned to once. It is a compile time error if a final variable is assigned to unless it is definitely unassigned (§16) immediately prior to the assignment.

In other words, it is perfectly legal. Moreover, it is considered a [best practice](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=23) to use `final` with local variables as much as possible.

> Consistently using final with local variables (when appropriate) can be useful as well. [...] A reasonable approach is to use final for local variables only if there is at least one non-final local variable in the method; this serves to quickly distinguish the non-final local variables from the others.

Comment: For class/instance, you should use final deliberatly, but for local variables (if not accessed by local/anonymous classes), it's more a matter of taste imho.

Answer (score 1):

who said we cannot. we can declare. You might have confused with static which cannot be used in methods.

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake! Probably you missed mentioning the reference variable and eclipse complains like 'Syntax error on token "final", invalid Type'.
Example `final Pojo  = new Pojo();` which has missing reference variable while it perfectly works if `final Pojo pojo = new Pojo();`
I am sure when you asked question here at SO by that time you didn't realize that silly mistake there.